# Proper way for converting to bigendian for network submission

Tags: python, sockets

I need to get an int through the network. Is this the proper way to convert to bytes in big-endian?

```
pack("I",socket.htonl(integer_value))
```

I unpack it as:

```
socket.ntohl(unpack("I",data)[0])
```

I noticed that pack-unpack also have the <> to use for endian conversion so I am not sure if I could just directly use that instead or if htonl is safer.

Comment: I think you're using the `struct` standard module. If so I believe you should use `pack(">I", ...)`, `>` stands for  big-endian.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use *only* the `struct` module for communicating with another system. By using the `htonl` first, you'll end up with an indeterminate order being transmitted.

Since you need to convert the integer into a string of bytes in order to send it to another system, you'll need to use `struct.pack` (because `htonl` just returns a different integer than the one passed as argument and you cannot directly send an integer). And in using `struct.pack` you must choose an endianness for that string of bytes (if you don't specify one, you'll get a default ordering which may not be the same on the receiving side so you really need to choose one).

Converting an integer to a sequence of bytes in a definite order is exactly what `struct.pack("!I", integer_value)` does and a sequence of bytes in a definite order is exactly what you *need* on the receiving end.

On the other hand, if you use `struct.pack("!I", socket.htonl(integer_value))`, what does that do? Well, first it puts the integer into big-endian order (network byte order), then it takes your already big-endian integer and converts it to bytes in "big-endian order". But, on a little endian machine, that will actually reverse the ordering again, and you will end up transmitting the integer in little-endian byte order if you do both those two operations.

But on a big-endian machine `htonl` is a no-op, and then you're converting the result into bytes in big-endian order.

So using `ntohl` actually *defeats the purpose* and a receiving machine would have to know the byte-order used on the sending machine in order to properly decode it. Observe...

Little-endian box:

```
>>> print(socket.htonl(27))
452984832
>>> print(struct.pack("!I", 27))
b'\x00\x00\x00\x1b'
>>> print(struct.pack("!I", socket.htonl(27)))
b'\x1b\x00\x00\x00'
```

Big-endian box:

```
>>> print(socket.htonl(27))
27
>>> print(struct.pack("!I", 27))
b'\x00\x00\x00\x1b'
>>> print(struct.pack("!I", socket.htonl(27)))
b'\x00\x00\x00\x1b'
```

Comment: Much more thorough response. Just so that I can make sure I understand this clear. I can use struct.pack with !I as option and then on the receiving system can use again struct.unpack with !I. What I mean is, does ! means decode or encode values with a big-endian-to-local and local-to-big-endian scheme?

Answer (score 2):

`struct.unpack()` uses '!' in the format specifiers for network byte order. But its the same as '>'...

Comment: So, as far as I understand either the way I did it or by just using unpack and pack's symbols ! < >. I think the way I did it, it automatically checks the endianess of the system.